# Bootstrap 4-beta.3 navbar with User Profile dropdown

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar, angular5

I'm working on having a standard Bootstrap 4 top navbar with search form and "profile" dropdown menu.
Only problem is the profile dropdown should be all the way right, and what happens is that the dropdown items scroll off the screen to the right.
Do I only need some margin-right settings to pull it in or am I missing something in my navbar class attribute ?

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" 
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://www.bobmazzo.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/bobmazzoCD.jpg" width="30" height="30" >
    </a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Patients</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Reports</a>
            </li>
            
        </ul>

        <form id="searchForm" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>

        <ul class="navbar-nav ">
            <!-- PROFILE DROPDOWN - scrolling off the page to the right -->
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navDropDownLink" 
                    data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Profile
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navDropDownLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Preferences</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logout</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
               
    </div>
    
</nav>
```

The plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/VM1VEbVcTmadljARolaq?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap has JavaScript and jQuery dependencies that you aren't loading there. That's the reason.

Try loading these:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The main issue was that you hadn't used a `container`.

Try this code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="http://www.bobmazzo.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/bobmazzoCD.jpg" width="30" height="30" >
</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Patients</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Reports</a>
                </li>

            </ul>

            <form id="searchForm" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>

            <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                <!-- PROFILE DROPDOWN - scrolling off the page to the right -->
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navDropDownLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Profile
            </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navDropDownLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Preferences</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logout</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>

</nav>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The container isn't absolutely necessary for navbars but it does help preventing issues of his nature as well as preventing your navbar from spanning all the way across wide 4K screens.

Comment: found the bootstrap loading issue before your answer. I realized I wasn't loading the three required scripts I had on my local project...however, I'm looking to properly place my User Profile menu to the right - WITHOUT it dropping off the screen.

Comment: OK, I'm looking into it.

Comment: Yes, that's it. THANK YOU.

Comment: BTW, Bootstrap released the version 4.0.0 final two days ago. There are no breaking changes compared to beta 3 though.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the alignment of the dropdown-menu to right worked for me. Add the Boostrap class `.dropdown-menu-right` to the dropdown-menu. Check out [menu alignment in dropdowns](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment)